# How to set initial congestion window size in android?

Tags: android, tcp, android-kernel, cwnd

I'm currently try to control initial congestion window in my android phone.

I found some useful method that works in desktop linux, however it does not work in android..

I tried solution that use ip route via adb shell as follows:

cmd/results

`ip route change default via 192.0.0.2 initcwnd 20`/`RTNETLINK answers: No such file or directory`

``` ip route | head -n 1 | while read p; do ``echo ip route change $p initcwnd 500 initrwnd 500``; done ```/result of cmd: `192.0.0.0/27 dev rmnet_data2 proto kernel scope link src 192.0.0.2 initcwnd 500 initrwnd 500`, however actual initcwnd does not changed.

If there is other way to change initial cwnd in android, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You try just adding a route instead:

```
ip route add default via 192.0.0.2 initcwnd 20
```

This will generally work but you may need to play with other parameters like `metric`.

It seems that Linux has issues changing the route parameters on a route that has been added by dhcp.